# Sharing wifi ,browsing

Tags: wifi, wireless

My neighbor gave me his WiFi password to use. He doesn't know much about computers, but he knows 'the basics'. Can he see in his browser history what sites I'm browsing, or my passwords?

Comment: I assume that you don't know much about computers too. Your Web traffic doesn't go through his computer, only through his wifi router. If he is using a standard router given by his provider, he cannot see you watching porn and typing your password.

Answer (score 1):

- If you browse websites that start with `http`, he could view the websites and its subpages you visit, what you post (e.g. facebook posts, google search queries, images) on these websites and that also includes the passwords you use for these websites. This requires more than "basic" knowledge, so even in this scenario, you should be pretty safe. Additionally, almost all reputable websites force you to use `https` (see below), so you should be safe in general.
- If you browse websites that start with `https` (often browser add a padlock symbol left of your address bar to denote that), he can see **which websites you visit** (e.g. facebook or google), but **not what you do on these websites**. For example, he can see that you're browsing Google, but he couldn't see what you're actually searching. He also would not be able read your passwords or any other data you enter or receive there. Note: If one of the websites you click in Google results uses `http`, he would be able to see everything you do with the website as mentioned above.
- Programs that you install on your computer, e.g. Microsoft Word or Dropbox that access the Internet will usually also use encrypted connections, like `https`. However, there isn't a simple way to ensure that they do. Again, reputable programs **will** use encryption, and then all he could tell is as outlined above.

If your browser suddenly warns you about an "unstrusted connection" or "invalid certificates", you should be careful about visiting sensitive pages or entering sensitive data (i.e. passwords). This is because those two warnings might indicate that someone is trying to tamper with your connection to the Internet in order to steal your data.